# Is there any way I could improve performance here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, background

First off, if you read through my question description and feel that I have not provided enough information, please let me know and inform me on what would be helpful in providing:

I'm using [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/), a "headless" Webkit engine, to dynamically generate rather large images of ten websites within each web request. I'm currently using Ruby threads to run these processes in parallel (each "process" is the generation of an image for a single website, and so I have ten threads running for each web request). However, even when doing this, a single request (containing the ten threads running in parallel) tends to take up to two minutes on my local Webrick server, which is simply unacceptable to ask the user to bear.

I'm definitely going to be moving these processes to a background task and then update the page with AJAX with the images so as not to tie up the web request and make the user experience better. However, I do not think that switching from threads to a background task (I'm thinking of using Resque) will actually shorten the time it takes to generate and display the images (I believe Resque can run its tasks in parallel so that I will not need threads?).

So my question is how can I generate and display these images more quickly? I'd appreciate any advice, ranging from what servers or environments to run this on to what tools to use. I'm not tied to anything I'm currently using.

Comment: Are you spinning up a new phantomjs instance for each image? Have you tried spinning up one and processing the requests serially instead? Have you profiled the phantomjs code to find out which bit is taking the time? How large are the images?

Comment: Yes, I'm launching a new instance for each image. I haven't tried spinning one up and processing them serially, but that's a pretty solid idea. I haven't profiled the phantomjs code, and I'm not sure how to. The images are 600x1200 pixels

Comment: Are the 10 websites different each time?  Can you cache the generated images to avoid generation on each request?

Comment: @cam yes, the websites will tend to be different each time. I already write the image file to my filesystem and check if it's there. If it's there, I serve it instead of starting up phantomjs.

Comment: Have you done any profiling to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: @Ben Nope, I'm completely new to profiling and I wouldn't even know where to start. Feel free to write an answer about how to approach profiling for this, and how to attack the bottlenecks once identified.

Comment: Sorry, I've only done very naïve profiling using ruby-prof (http://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-prof/0.10.7/frames), so I'm not qualified to do that.

Comment: Why not starting from couple suggestions I already gave here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phantomjs/7yiZg1aVg8k/ijZ2POoNajsJ

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to make any solid suggestions, but:

> I'm currently using Ruby threads to run these processes in parallel.

What do you call a "process" here? The retrieval of ten web sites together, or the retrieval of each of those ten? If you do the ten requests in parallel, that would be faster than the groups of ten being run in parallel, but those ten requests being run serially within each group.

Comment: Each process is the retrieval of one website, and so I run one thread for each of the ten websites. What information could I provide so people could make better suggestions?